# Querying table with dates in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I need to query a MySQL database table that looks like this:

```
Bike  Owner  Date
-----------------------
1     Oscar  2014-02-02
2     Oscar  2014-02-02
3     John   2014-04-28
4     Jane   2014-05-29
2     John   2015-04-16
3     Mike   2015-06-16
1     Bob    2015-07-16
4     John   2015-08-16
2     Mike   2016-04-16
3     John   2016-04-16
```

It contains 4 bikes and as soon as the bike switches from owner, a new record is placed within this table. Since this table doesn't have an 'until' attribute, I am stuck creating a query that gets all the owners of all bikes at a specific date, say 2015-07-06.

Does anyone now how to do this in an easy way? I can think of ways of doing this by creating functions or temporary tables, but this seems way too far fetched for such an easy question.

Thanks!

Comment: How to do what? You didn't specify what you're trying to do. What you have by way of SQL should also be posted, to show your effort. Please read [How do I ask a good question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses an explicit `join` and aggregation:

```
select b.*
from (select bike, max(date) as maxdate
      from bikes b
      where date <= '2015-07-06
      group by bike
     ) bd join
     bikes b
     on b.bike = bd.bike and b.date = bd.maxdate;
```

A somewhat shorter way to write this:

```
select b.*
from bikes b
where b.date = (select max(b2.date) from bikes b2 where b2.bike = b.bike);
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your requirement correctly then it is very straight foreword query, getting all owner of bike on specific date

```
select b.*
from bikes b
where CAST(b.date AS DATE) = '2015-07-06'
```